# How to override the ServiceHost in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

The communication object, ExtendingWCFwithServiceHost.clsMyOwnHost, has overridden the virtual function OnOpening but it does not call version defined in the base class.

I'm getting this error while overriding the OnOpening method of the ServiceHost class.

Comment: Just add a call to `base.OnOpening(....)` in your method - or am I missing something here?? Can you show us your code, please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message explains the problem - you are overriding the `OnOpening` method but are not calling the base implementation. Your override should look like this:

```
protected override OnOpening()
{
    //additional processing
    base.OnOpening();
}
```

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041.aspx) explains the `ICommunicationObject` state machine and says:

> While
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnOpen(System.TimeSpan),
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnClose(System.TimeSpan),
>   and
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnAbort
>   have no default implementation, the
>   other callbacks do have a default
>   implementation which is necessary for
>   state machine correctness. If you
>   override those methods be sure to call
>   the base implementation or correctly
>   replace it.